# MySQL Database Organization: Storing lists of words

Tags: mysql, database-design

A project I'm currently working on involves parsing a lot of text, taking out "stop words", and then performing certain operations on the article for each user of the site. In the end, I'll need a list of the unique words of the article, stop words removed, along with a count of how many times that word was used. For example:

```
computer: 6
artificial: 5
robot: 2
```

I'm wondering how I would best go about storing data of that sort in a MySQL database. The obvious answer is to just store a plain list "computer:6 artificial:5 robot:2" and there's nothing wrong with this approach except that it feels ugly. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would store this in a table that has a column for the word and a column for the count.  The likely structure would be:

```
create table WordCounts (
    word varchar(255) not null,
    articleid int not null,
    cnt int not null
);
```

You would probably want an index on `word` and `article`.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible. With your solution, I would need a table for each article and there are too many for that, and there are new articles every day. Alternatively, I could have one table that has words with and id, and then another column that matches a word id, with an article and its count in that article. My only worry here is that the sheer size of this table will be huge, but maybe I'm overestimating it. I mean just 1 article could have 1000+ words, and I'll potentially have 100s of articles. Perhaps is that too much to store in any fashion?

Comment: @williamg . . . Then you would add another column called `articleId`, and it would be close to a proper inverted index.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try another approach, like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or something. This kind of database (document-oriented) is great to store these kind of data. But the kind of processing that you will apply to that data the make one approach better than another.

But, with relation data, you can try 3 tables: Article, Words and one to join those twos.

Article will contains informations about the article, words is a table with all words found until now and the table that joins those two ( article_id, word_id, count )

I think it's a good way to save the data with relational database because the "word" table will be limited. However, if you need the word in plain text, maybe it will be better try the way eluded by [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) ( you save a join )

But, again, the way you store your data is strongly related to the way you're going to process it.